# how to multiply two indicator function together in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have two indicator functions, say `x(t)` and `y(t)`. Note that the indicator functions may not have fixed length and parameters until the user input. For example, I enter `x(t)` and `y(t)` as follow to suit my situation:
`Rangex=[-inf,1,2,3], Parax=[0,0.5,0.4,0], x(t)=@(t)find(Rangex<=t,1,'last')`; `Rangey=[-inf,1.5,2.5], Paray=[0,0.3,0], y(t)=@(t)find(Rangey<=t,1,'last')`. Note that here, if I change the `Rangex`, `Rangey`, `Parax` and `Paray`, then I can get another indicator function. How to multiply them? I understand if I know its specific form, I can write it, but the problem is I do not know its exact form in general. How to express the product?

Comment: If you multiply them what is the expected output?

Comment: I would expect the program to output what the corresponding Range and parameters if I multiply them, i.e. take the example, the range is [-inf,1,1.5,2,2.5,3] and the parameter is [0,0.15,0.15,0.12,0]

Comment: what is the role of `Parax` and `Paray` in the function?

Comment: The role of `Parax` and `Paray` is the parameter for the indicator function. For example, if the indicator function is defined on [0,1) and [1,2) with parameters 0.1 and 0.2, then the function is 0.1*1_{[0,1)}(t)+0.2*1_{[1,2)}(t).

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function but multiple parameters:

```
f = @(t,Range) find(Range<=t,1,'last')
```

instead of multiplying two function you can multiple two parameters using `unique` function

```
Rangex=[-inf,1,2,3]
Rangey=[-inf,1.5,2.5]
Rangexy = unique([Rangex Rangey])
```

and

```
Parax=[0,0.5,0.4,0]
Paray=[0,0.3,0]
Paraxy = unique([Parax Paray])
```

then call the function with new parameters

```
t = 2;
result = f(t, Rangexy )
```